# How to solve this error?-'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u200e' in position 158023: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, urllib

I am using python 3.6.3
and the code which i was running is-

```
import re
import urllib.request
#https://www.google.com/finance?q=
url="http://www.google.com/finance?q="
stock=input("Enter the stock you want to search=")
url1=url+stock
print(url1)
try:
    headers={}
    headers['User-Agent']="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 
    Safari/537.36"
    req=urllib.request.Request(url1,headers=headers)
    resp=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respdata=resp.read()
    respdata1=respdata.decode("utf-8")
    f=open("webdata.txt","w")
    f.write(str(respdata1))
    f.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

This program shows the current stock price of any company.

Comment: Why don't you open the file in binary mode and write `resp.read()` without decoding it?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried your program, I didn't get the actual error you were getting. Instead, I was getting `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`. After I modified the code, it seemed to be working. Here's the updated code:

```
import re
import urllib.request

url = "http://www.google.com/finance?q="
stock = input("Enter the stock you want to search=")
url1 = url + stock
print(url1)

try:
    req = urllib.request.Request(url1)
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)')
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132')
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Safari/537.36')
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respdata = resp.read()
    respdata1 = respdata.decode("utf-8")
    f = open("webdata.txt", "w")
    f.write(str(respdata1))
    f.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

When I ran this code, it created `webdata.txt`. However, the contents do not contain the stock price of the company. Instead, it contains the output that you would get when you do a google search for the company. So you might want to modify the URL that you use for querying.